# Reading local text file into a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, text

I have a text file in the same folder as my JavaScript file. Both files are stored on my local machine. The .txt file is one word on each line like:

```
red 
green
blue
black
```

I want to read in each line and store them in a JavaScript array as efficiently as possible. How do you do this?

Comment: This "Javascript - read local text file" question/answer looks like a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file

Comment: What is your JavaScript running? Is it embedded in a webpage? Does "local" mean "on the same HTTP host"? Or are you running it with Windows Scripting Host? Or Node.js? And wanting to access your file system rather than something over HTTP?

Comment: Is it for server side(Node) or client  side(web-browser)?  You can't do it for client side coding.

Comment: I just have both the .js file and the .txt file locally. I'm trying to get it working locally first before deploying it on the web... but it sounds like it cannot work that way locally?

Comment: @dan-man, i saw the linked solution that Marc posted. Do I need to communicate over http to read the txt file? It seems like that solution is already deployed on the web though.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Using Node.js**

sync mode:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt");
var textByLine = text.split("\n")
```

async mode:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("./mytext.txt", function(text){
    var textByLine = text.split("\n")
});
```

**UPDATE**

As of at least Node 6, `readFileSync` returns a `Buffer`, so it must first be converted to a string in order for `split` to work:

```
var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt").toString('utf-8');
```

Or

```
var text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt", "utf-8");
```

Comment: how to put them into an array ?

Comment: Split function returns an array, and textByLine is already an array

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on Node 6, which returns a `Buffer`

Comment: This gives me an "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"! What am I missing?

Comment: I think you try use "require" function from browser environment, right?

Comment: require is not a function

Comment: Where you run your code?

Comment: "require" is one of the two core modules of Node.js and is available globally.

Comment: does this mean this will only work if i install Node.js?

Comment: The question clearly does not specify that Node.js is being used.  This answer is a Node.js answer.

Comment: why is a node js an answer for this question