# typescript - Read a txt file and store it in an array on Ionic (not on device)

Tags: javascript, file, typescript, ionic3

In my Ionic project I need to read a local txt file and convert it in an array at every "\n". I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857458/reading-local-text-file-into-a-javascript-array) answer, but I can't use the function since it tells me that `readFile` (or `readFileAsync`) is not a function.
I need to open it while running locally on my browser, not on device, so I'm not looking for a solution using cordova and ionic-native

Comment: Use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I can't find how to load the file from a path ... Every method needs a File or a Blob, but I don't know how to create them

Comment: Add a file input or drop zone in page or if file is on local server make ajax request and then you don't even need FileReader...just parse the text