# How can I read lines from .txt file, save in array, and print array asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, async-await, asynchronous-javascript

I have a `.txt` file that I want to save in a JS array and then `console.log` that array. I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857458/reading-local-text-file-into-a-javascript-array) how to read the file into an array, but the problem is when I try to `console.log` the array, it logs it as empty. Here's my code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let arr = []
let fileReader = async () => {
  await fs.readFile('temp.txt', (err, data) => { 
    if (err) throw err; 
    console.log(data.toString()); // confirming that line is successfully read
    arr.push(data.toString());
  })
  console.log(arr)
}
fileReader()
```

I figured that the `console.log` would wait until the array had finished being populated in `fs.readFile()`, and so it would print the populated array. Note that I `console.log` every line when it's read, in order to confirm that text is indeed being pushed to the array.

Does anyone know why this approach wouldn't work, or how I can do it differently? I want to stick with the asynchronous `readFile` rather than the synchronous `readFileSync` for now. Note that if I *did* want to do it synchronously, this code works:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let arr = fs.readFileSync("temp.txt").toString('utf-8').split("\n")
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: That's a fairly broad question. Have you done any debugging to see where it's failing? You might use breakpoints rather than console logs to eliminate timing ambiguity.

Comment: @isherwood I did use breakpoints to confirm that lines of text were being successfully read and pushed to the array. I also console.logged each line as it was being read. I've updated the original question to show this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: `fs.readFile` returns immediately. the asynchronous logic is provided by passing a callback, so the `console.log(arr)` line should be place inside the callback itself. An alternative would be turning the `readFile` function into a real `async` function, for example promisifying it.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Understood. Do you want to make this a reply so I can accept it?

Comment: @gkeenley don't worry, it's ok. If you need further explanation I can write an answer, otherwise "accept" the comment :)

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Ok so my understanding is that fs.readFile() returns immediately, ie BEFORE its callback has finished executing. So even though I `await` it, it returns and `console.log(arr)` runs before the callback has populated the array. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Just an advice: always make sure that the awaited method actually returns a `Promise`. if it does not, the `await` operator is useless and it is better to omit it, to avoid confusing people who read your code. A simple rule of thumb is: callback and Promises do not usually get along, but if the async/await version with `Promise` is available, then go for it.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have your file data after `data.toString()` you can split it by `\n`.
For example:

```js
let data = data.toString()
let data_rows_arr = data.split('\n') //defines a new line seperator.

for(row of data_rows_arr){
   //Do something with your rows
}
```

Hope that helped you :)